# CakePHP 3 created and modified not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a model (Addresses) with the following fields:

```
    id: char(36) #using uuid
    name: varchar(150)
#city, state, etc here
    created: timestamp
    modified: timestamp
```

In my AddressesTable class I have:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('addresses');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
}
```

In my controller, I have this in the edit method:

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    $addressesTable = TableRegistry::get('Addresses');
    $address = $addressesTable->get($id);
    if ($this->request->is(array('post','put'))) {
        $address = $addressesTable->patchEntity($address, $this->request->data);
        if ($addressesTable->save($address)) {
            $this->Flash->success('The address has been saved.');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'addresses']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('The address could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('address'));

}
```

The problem I'm running into is this. According to everything I've read, this should 'update' the record (which it does), and update the 'modified' field in the DB to the current timestamp (which it also does). However, in addition, it also updates the created timestamp (which, it should NOT do).

What am I missing here?

I need this to update ONLY the modified column and NOT the created column on save.

Comment: What you are looking for is the default behavior, and it's working just fine. Make sure that you are using the latest release, that `$address->isNew()` is `false` when saving the entity, and that you don't have any DBMS level triggers, auto-updaters or the like defined that would update the column.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out there was a trigger on that column (created) to fire on update. Removed that and it now works as I would expect.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem using CakePHP 3.4. I solved using this in my Model/Table:

```
 public function initialize(array $config)
  {
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
  }
```

More informations here: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html

Comment: My case was similar: I had the Table file missing, that way using auto tables, which apparently didn't have this `addBehaviour` configuration.